# Expander IsExpanded binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

In the following code:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754027.aspx

How to Bind IsExpanded to the MyData list of objects, where each object has the IsExpanded property?

```
<Expander IsExpanded={Binding Path=IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay} />
```

This doesn't work!

```
MyData is List<GroupNode>;
```

GroupNode is a class containing notify property changed property IsExpanded.

So, if I open one of the expander manually it should set the IsExpanded property to true of that MyData's GroupNode.

Comment: if the datacontext of this Expander is an object with a boolean property called IsExpanded - it would work:) so whats DataContext of your Expander? And what do you want the expander behave?

Comment: I think we'll need a little more context, like the surrounding XAML and a snippet of the view model.

Comment: I want to set the IsExpanded boolean property of MyData's each object to set to true if that group is expanded, so that if i reset the data I can set those nodes' isExpanded back to true.

Comment: You might need to add 'mode=TwoWay" to the binding.  I'm not sure what the default for Expander is.

Comment: It doesn't make sense... Are you asking how to bind IsExpanded to be true if *any* GroupNode in MyData has its IsExpanded property set to `true`?  That's a very odd design.  The issue you're having is a *code smell* telling you that your design is going against the grain.

Comment: @Will, No i want it to be two way, if i open an expander from UI it should set the IsExpanded in viewmodel as true and after that when i reset my data I should be able to set these properties to true so that UI retains the expanded nodes.

Comment: @WhoIsNinja: So, the Expander is found within the DataTemplate of an ItemsControl that is bound to MyData?

Comment: I'm sure the community will be able to answer this eventually, but the sooner you learn to use [snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) or a similar tool, the better. It will highlight broken bindings in red and tell you what the binding error is. Debugging WPF without a tool like this will not be fun.

Comment: @default you reminded me I forgot my standard WPF databinding comment:  First thing you need to do is turn up debug messages for databinding: http://i.imgur.com/UAxJO.png Next, re-run and check the output window and see what errors are there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not very easy to do, because the `DataContext` of the `GroupItem` is an instance of [`CollectionViewGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup.aspx), and this class doesn't have a `IsExpanded` property. You can however specify a converter in the `GroupDescription`, allowing you to return a custom value for the "name" of the group (the `CollectionViewGroup.Name` property). This "name" can be anything; in your case, you need it to be a class that wraps the group name (e.g. grouping key) and has a `IsExpanded` property:

Here's an example:

```
public class ExpandableGroupName : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private object _name;
    public object Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name != value)
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    private bool? _isExpanded = false;
    public bool? IsExpanded
    {
        get { return _isExpanded; }
        set
        {
            if (_isExpanded != value)
            {
                _isExpanded = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsExpanded");
            }
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return object.Equals(obj, _name);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _name != null ? _name.GetHashCode() : 0;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _name != null ? _name.ToString() : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

And here's the converter:

```
public class ExpandableGroupNameConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new ExpandableGroupName { Name = value };
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var groupName = value as ExpandableGroupName;
        if (groupName != null)
            return groupName.Name;
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

In XAML, just declare the grouping as follows:

```
<my:ExpandableGroupNameConverter x:Key="groupConverter" />
<CollectionViewSource x:Key='src' 
                      Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyData}, 
                               XPath=Item}">
  <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="@Catalog" Converter="{StaticResource groupConverter}" />
  </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

And bind the `IsExpanded` property like that:

```
<Expander IsExpanded={Binding Path=Name.IsExpanded} />
```

Comment: its not straightforward, and will make my code complicated at lot of places. I'm not sure if this is the only solution to the problem. There's no way to bind it using FindAncestor?

Comment: Yes, I know it's not ideal... but at least it works. I haven't found a better way yet.

Comment: I'm not sure how a binding using FindAncestor would help you... Each group would need to be bound to a different object, so I don't see how you intend to do that

Comment: I'm searching for a solution for this problem for some hours now (I'm not very experienced with WPF so far). About 1 hour ago I thought about doing it exactly like you did but then decided to continue searching for a cleaner solution. Seems like there is none but now I'm feeling a little more confident. (Let's see if the code reviewer will accept it)